# Zxing Maven Compile Error

Tags: java, android, maven, intellij-idea, zxing

I can compile zxing which is included as an AndroidLibrary to my project without problem through intellij idea, but when I want to compile it with maven, it gives errors. Here is my pom.xml and the error

**POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.somecompany.zxing</groupId>
    <artifactId>zxing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>apklib</packaging>
    <name>zxing library</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <platform.version>4.1.1.4</platform.version>
        <sdk_path>D:\Android</sdk_path>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${platform.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
            <version>r7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>10</platform>
                        <path>${sdk_path}</path>
                    </sdk>
                    <dexOptimize>false</dexOptimize>
                    <dex>
                        <preDex>false</preDex>
                        <preDexLibLocation>/tmp/predexedLibs</preDexLibLocation>
                    </dex>
                    <dexCoreLibrary>true</dexCoreLibrary>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**THE ERROR**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building zxing library 1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ zxing ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\Projects\Inherd\Libraries\trunk\zxing\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.8.0:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) @ zxing ---
[INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] Manifest merging disabled. Using project manifest only
[INFO] D:\Android\build-tools\19.0.1\aapt.exe [package, --non-constant-id, -m, -J, D:\Projects\Inherd\Libraries\trunk\zxing\target\generated-sources\r, -M, D:\Projects\Inherd\Libraries\trunk\zxing\AndroidManifest.xml, -S, D:\Projects\Inherd\Libraries\trunk\zxing\res, --auto-add-overlay, -A, D:\Projects\Inherd\Libraries\trunk\zxing\assets, -I, D:\Android\platforms\android-10\android.jar]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ zxing ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Projects\Inherd\Libraries\trunk\zxing\target\generated-sources\extracted-dependencies\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ zxing ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 78 source files to D:\Projects\Inherd\Libraries\trunk\zxing\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] COMPILATION WARNING : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/share/ShareActivity.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[WARNING] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/share/ShareActivity.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] 2 warnings 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraManager.java:[26,24] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PlanarYUVLuminanceSource
  location: package com.google.zxing
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraManager.java:[300,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PlanarYUVLuminanceSource
  location: class com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.CameraManager
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHandler.java:[23,24] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PlanarYUVLuminanceSource
  location: package com.google.zxing
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHandler.java:[110,39] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PlanarYUVLuminanceSource
  location: class com.google.zxing.client.android.DecodeHandler
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHintManager.java:[141,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getValueType()
  location: variable hintType of type com.google.zxing.DecodeHintType
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHintManager.java:[147,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getValueType()
  location: variable hintType of type com.google.zxing.DecodeHintType
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHintManager.java:[152,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getValueType()
  location: variable hintType of type com.google.zxing.DecodeHintType
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHintManager.java:[157,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getValueType()
  location: variable hintType of type com.google.zxing.DecodeHintType
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHintManager.java:[172,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getValueType()
  location: variable hintType of type com.google.zxing.DecodeHintType
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHintManager.java:[194,80] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getValueType()
  location: variable hintType of type com.google.zxing.DecodeHintType
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHintManager.java:[218,21] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getValueType()
  location: variable hintType of type com.google.zxing.DecodeHintType
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHintManager.java:[223,23] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getValueType()
  location: variable hintType of type com.google.zxing.DecodeHintType
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity.java:[745,76] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable UPC_EAN_EXTENSION
  location: class com.google.zxing.ResultMetadataType
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity.java:[748,88] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable UPC_EAN_EXTENSION
  location: class com.google.zxing.ResultMetadataType
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraManager.java:[306,16] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PlanarYUVLuminanceSource
  location: class com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.CameraManager
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHandler.java:[78,5] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PlanarYUVLuminanceSource
  location: class com.google.zxing.client.android.DecodeHandler
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/wifi/WifiConfigManager.java:[131,35] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method isHidden()
  location: variable wifiResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.WifiParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/encode/QRCodeEncoder.java:[304,57] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getURLs()
  location: variable contact of type com.google.zxing.client.result.AddressBookParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/AddressBookResultHandler.java:[126,33] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getNicknames()
  location: variable addressResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.AddressBookParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/AddressBookResultHandler.java:[138,33] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getURLs()
  location: variable addressResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.AddressBookParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/AddressBookResultHandler.java:[140,33] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getGeo()
  location: variable addressResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.AddressBookParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/AddressBookResultHandler.java:[196,36] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getURLs()
  location: variable result of type com.google.zxing.client.result.AddressBookParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/CalendarResultHandler.java:[65,40] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getOrganizer()
  location: variable calendarResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.CalendarParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/CalendarResultHandler.java:[76,38] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method isStartAllDay()
  location: variable calendarResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.CalendarParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/CalendarResultHandler.java:[80,38] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getAttendees()
  location: variable calendarResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.CalendarParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/CalendarResultHandler.java:[150,36] incompatible types
  required: java.util.Date
  found:    java.lang.String
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/CalendarResultHandler.java:[151,46] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method isStartAllDay()
  location: variable calResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.CalendarParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/CalendarResultHandler.java:[153,32] incompatible types
  required: java.util.Date
  found:    java.lang.String
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/CalendarResultHandler.java:[155,20] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method isEndAllDay()
  location: variable calResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.CalendarParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/CalendarResultHandler.java:[162,48] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method isEndAllDay()
  location: variable calResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.CalendarParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/CalendarResultHandler.java:[166,39] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getOrganizer()
  location: variable calResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.CalendarParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/CalendarResultHandler.java:[167,39] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getAttendees()
  location: variable calResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.CalendarParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/ProductResultHandler.java:[81,55] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getRawText()
  location: class com.google.zxing.client.result.ExpandedProductParsedResult
[INFO] 33 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 23.176s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Feb 21 10:19:50 EET 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/351M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project zxing: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraManager.java:[26,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class PlanarYUVLuminanceSource
[ERROR] location: package com.google.zxing
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraManager.java:[300,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class PlanarYUVLuminanceSource
[ERROR] location: class com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.CameraManager
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHandler.java:[23,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class PlanarYUVLuminanceSource
[ERROR] location: package com.google.zxing
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHandler.java:[110,39] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class PlanarYUVLuminanceSource
[ERROR] location: class com.google.zxing.client.android.DecodeHandler
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHintManager.java:[141,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getValueType()
[ERROR] location: variable hintType of type com.google.zxing.DecodeHintType
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHintManager.java:[147,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getValueType()
[ERROR] location: variable hintType of type com.google.zxing.DecodeHintType
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHintManager.java:[152,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getValueType()
[ERROR] location: variable hintType of type com.google.zxing.DecodeHintType
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHintManager.java:[157,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getValueType()
[ERROR] location: variable hintType of type com.google.zxing.DecodeHintType
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHintManager.java:[172,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getValueType()
[ERROR] location: variable hintType of type com.google.zxing.DecodeHintType
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHintManager.java:[194,80] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getValueType()
[ERROR] location: variable hintType of type com.google.zxing.DecodeHintType
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHintManager.java:[218,21] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getValueType()
[ERROR] location: variable hintType of type com.google.zxing.DecodeHintType
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHintManager.java:[223,23] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getValueType()
[ERROR] location: variable hintType of type com.google.zxing.DecodeHintType
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity.java:[745,76] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable UPC_EAN_EXTENSION
[ERROR] location: class com.google.zxing.ResultMetadataType
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity.java:[748,88] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable UPC_EAN_EXTENSION
[ERROR] location: class com.google.zxing.ResultMetadataType
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraManager.java:[306,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class PlanarYUVLuminanceSource
[ERROR] location: class com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.CameraManager
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHandler.java:[78,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class PlanarYUVLuminanceSource
[ERROR] location: class com.google.zxing.client.android.DecodeHandler
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/wifi/WifiConfigManager.java:[131,35] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method isHidden()
[ERROR] location: variable wifiResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.WifiParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/encode/QRCodeEncoder.java:[304,57] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getURLs()
[ERROR] location: variable contact of type com.google.zxing.client.result.AddressBookParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/AddressBookResultHandler.java:[126,33] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getNicknames()
[ERROR] location: variable addressResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.AddressBookParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/AddressBookResultHandler.java:[138,33] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getURLs()
[ERROR] location: variable addressResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.AddressBookParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/AddressBookResultHandler.java:[140,33] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getGeo()
[ERROR] location: variable addressResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.AddressBookParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/AddressBookResultHandler.java:[196,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getURLs()
[ERROR] location: variable result of type com.google.zxing.client.result.AddressBookParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/CalendarResultHandler.java:[65,40] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getOrganizer()
[ERROR] location: variable calendarResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.CalendarParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/CalendarResultHandler.java:[76,38] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method isStartAllDay()
[ERROR] location: variable calendarResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.CalendarParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/CalendarResultHandler.java:[80,38] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getAttendees()
[ERROR] location: variable calendarResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.CalendarParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/CalendarResultHandler.java:[150,36] incompatible types
[ERROR] required: java.util.Date
[ERROR] found:    java.lang.String
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/CalendarResultHandler.java:[151,46] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method isStartAllDay()
[ERROR] location: variable calResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.CalendarParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/CalendarResultHandler.java:[153,32] incompatible types
[ERROR] required: java.util.Date
[ERROR] found:    java.lang.String
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/CalendarResultHandler.java:[155,20] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method isEndAllDay()
[ERROR] location: variable calResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.CalendarParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/CalendarResultHandler.java:[162,48] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method isEndAllDay()
[ERROR] location: variable calResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.CalendarParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/CalendarResultHandler.java:[166,39] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getOrganizer()
[ERROR] location: variable calResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.CalendarParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/CalendarResultHandler.java:[167,39] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getAttendees()
[ERROR] location: variable calResult of type com.google.zxing.client.result.CalendarParsedResult
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/Inherd/Libraries/trunk/zxing/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/ProductResultHandler.java:[81,55] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getRawText()
[ERROR] location: class com.google.zxing.client.result.ExpandedProductParsedResult
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the latest and correct version of pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.a.zxing</groupId>
    <artifactId>zxing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>apklib</packaging>
    <name>zxing library</name>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${android.platform.version}</version>
            <!--<exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>-->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
            <version>r7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>

                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>${android.sdk.platform}</platform>
                        <path>${android.sdk.path}</path>
                    </sdk>
                    <dexOptimize>false</dexOptimize>
                    <dex>
                        <preDex>false</preDex>
                        <preDexLibLocation>/tmp/predexedLibs</preDexLibLocation>
                    </dex>
                    <dexCoreLibrary>true</dexCoreLibrary>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals><goal>add-source</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>srccore</source>
                               <!-- <source>gen</source>-->
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using a very old version of the library in your dependencies (2.0).

See http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.zxing%7Ccore%7C2.3.0%7Cjar